# Speed up deinterleave and concatenation for TIFF

Tags: performance, matlab, concatenation, video-processing, tiff

I work in a neuro-lab that records pictures of mouse brains. The raw files that the cameras record to record pictures from alternating cameras (picture of brain, picture of mouse head, picture of brain, etc) We're converting these files to TIFF, deinterleaving them, and then concatenating the files.

The concatenation is far too slow to be of any use. I'm not yet learned enough in Matlab to be able to troubleshoot. How can we improve the speed of this code?

```
%convert micam raw to tiff using image j
javaaddpath 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\java\mij.jar';
javaaddpath 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\java\ij.jar';
MIJ.start('C:\users\lee\desktop\imagej');
MIJ.run('Install...', 'install=[C:\\Users\\lee\\Desktop\\ImageJ\\macros\\Matthias\\Helmchen Macros modified djm.ijm]');
MIJ.run('Run...', 'path=[C:\\Users\\lee\\Desktop\\ImageJ\\macros\\Matthias\\Helmchen Macros modified djm.ijm]');
MIJ.run('Convert MiCam Raw to TIFF');
pause (30); %to prevent race condition, needs to be fixed to wait for input
MIJ.exit;
%prepare tiff stack folder fast
myFolder = uigetdir;
cd(myFolder);
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.tif');
tifffiles = dir(filePattern);
count = length(tifffiles);
for z = 1:count
A = tifffiles.name;  
I = imreadtiffstack (A, 256); 
%crop tiff stack
sizecrop = size(I);
framenum = sizecrop(3); 
cropcollector = ones([100 101 256] , 'uint16'); %preallocates matrix for depositing cropped frames 
for k = 1:framenum
    frame = I(:,:,k);
    I2 = imcrop(frame,[20 0 100 100]);
    cropcollector(:,:,k)=I2;
%deinterleaves tiff stack
sizedinlv = size(cropcollector);
framenumdinlv = sizedinlv(3);
oddcollector = ones([100 101 128], 'uint16'); %preallocates array for odd deinterleaved frames
evencollector = ones([100 101 128], 'uint16'); %preallocates array for even deinterleaved frames
countodd = 0;
counteven = 0;
for k2 = (1:framenumdinlv)
    if mod(k2, 2)==1
    framedinlv = cropcollector(:,:,k2);
    countodd = countodd +1;
    oddcollector(:,:,countodd)=framedinlv;
    else
        framedinlv = cropcollector(:,:,k2);
        counteven = counteven + 1;
        evencollector(:,:,counteven)=framedinlv;
%concatenate        
       if mod (z, 2)==1;
        oddhold = ones([100 101 128], 'uint16');
        evenhold = ones([100 101 128], 'uint16'); 
        oddhold = repmat(oddcollector, 1);
        evenhold = repmat(evencollector, 1);
         else
          odd = num2str(1);
          even = num2str(2);
          brain = ones([100 101 256], 'uint16');
          mouse = ones([100 101 256], 'uint16'); 
         % nameoddframes = strcat(A(1:10), odd);
          %nameevenframes = strcat(A(1:10), even);
          brain = cat(3, oddhold, oddcollector);
          mouse = cat(3, evenhold, evencollector);
         end
      end
  end
  end
  end
%background subtraction
```

Comment: Rather than posting you entire code, it's much more helpful if you create a minimal example of the part that is problematic. That way you yourself can understand which specific aspects are slow (have you profiled your code?) and ask much more focussed questions that have a much better chance of getting quality answers here.

Comment: Ok, can do...  Sorry, I'm very new here, and very new to any sort of programming.  My background is in biology.  I shall learn!

Comment: And please explain what you mean by interleave/deinterleave. Are you referring to the RGB color channels? Or are these multi-image TIFFs? [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#f25-721031) can read multi-images TIFFs and [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#f25-720267) can create them. If all you're doing is trying to pull out a subset of images from a TIFF and save them to a new file, I'd look at those. Or are you trying to make a movie?

Comment: The profiler might also help you isolate hot spots (in terms of performance) http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html

Comment: There's some issues with the code - for every "k" you are going through the "k2" loop which I don't think you intended to do. Read up on matrix indexing in matlab as well: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html